# Were notable physicists great at math or computing?

Tags: mathematics, physics, biographical-details

Were famous or popular physicists like Galileo, Newton, Einstein, Feynman predominantly mathematicians or scientists (computing, experimenting, engineering, etc.)?

I am curious if people like the ones mentioned above spent much time on things that are more "purely" mathematical like proofs, or did they use math more as a means to an end and mostly compute number values based on experimentally-gathered inputs?

For example, there are stories about Feynman being good at computing and integrating or Newton "inventing" calculus, but I haven't heard anything about them proving anything in the way the Greeks did, or more recently Fermat, Euler, Gauss. Also, the university I attended only requires up through calculus and linear algebra for a BS in physics.

Comment: It varied. Certainly Newton and Maxwell were great mathematicians, not only physicists. On the other hand, Galileo, Hooke and Faraday were not.

Comment: This question is a bit too wide.  Every researcher had to know enough math to be able to analyse their data in a useful and valid way. Many mathematicians were useless in the "real world," and many engineers the reverse.

Comment: "_Newton 'inventing' calculus_" was not at all in a mathematically rigorous form like Cauchy et al. would put it in later.

Comment: This is quite a broad question, and it also elicits opinion-based answers.

Comment: @Geremia that is the type of information i was looking for, which is why i mentioned mathematical proof writing.

Comment: @tau Then narrow the scope of your question down to calculus, if that's what you want to ask. However, there's already a related question here: "[Did Newton and Leibniz lack rigour?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3301/232)."